# Partial match for a dataset using vector in R

Tags: r, nlp, stringr

I have one dataset consisting of car brand names with other data (*test1*), and a vector of all the unique shortened car brand names (*test*).

```
test<-c("Rolls Royce", "Toyota", "Tesla", "BMW","Ford", "Mercedes")
test1<- data.frame(Brand = c("Mercedes Benz", "Bayerische Motoren Werke (BMW)",
                 "Ford Motor Corp.", "Rolls Royce", 
                 "Tesla", "Mercedes Benz", "Ford Motor"),
      Ratings = c(6,6,4,9,8,8,6))
```

How do I do a partial string match to the dataset (*test1*) using the string vector of unique car names (*test*) and change the Brand values of *test1* to search and match the values of *test*?

I can do this for each entry, though I'd like to see if there's a faster way to obtain the result:

```
library(data.table)
test1[test1$Brand %like% "Rolls Royce", ]$Brand <-"Rolls Royce"
test1[test1$Brand %like% "Toyota", ]$Brand <-"Toyota"
test1[test1$Brand %like% "Tesla", ]$Brand <-"Tesla"
test1[test1$Brand %like% "BMW", ]$Brand <-"BMW"
test1[test1$Brand %like% "Ford", ]$Brand <-"Ford"
test1[test1$Brand %like% "Mercedes", ]$Brand <-"Mercedes"
```

This is the result I'd like to obtain for the above example:

```
data.frame(Brand = c("Mercedes", "BMW",
                 "Ford", "Rolls Royce", 
                 "Tesla", "Mercedes", "Ford"),
      Ratings = c(6,6,4,9,8,8,6))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can paste the strings in `test` together and use `str_extract`

```
stringr::str_extract(test1$Brand, paste0('\\b', test, '\\b', collapse = "|")) 
#[1] "Mercedes" "BMW"  "Ford"   "Rolls Royce" "Tesla"  "Mercedes"    "Ford"
```

Word boundaries (`\\b`) are added in the pattern to avoid matching incomplete words like `"ford"` matching with `"afford"`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `agrep` fuzzy matching.

```
test1 <- transform(test1, 
                   Brand.new=gsub("\\d+$", "", names(sort(unlist(sapply(test, function(x) 
                     agrep(x, Brand)))))))
test1
#                            Brand Ratings   Brand.new
# 1                  Mercedes Benz       6    Mercedes
# 2 Bayerische Motoren Werke (BMW)       6         BMW
# 3               Ford Motor Corp.       4        Ford
# 4                    Rolls Royce       9 Rolls Royce
# 5                          Tesla       8       Tesla
# 6                  Mercedes Benz       8    Mercedes
# 7                     Ford Motor       6        Ford
```